# Open cv 'SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow' in namespace 'cv'

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I am new to OpenCV and Yolo. I am trying to setup Yolo Mark for creating a training set.
current OpenCV version 3.4.2.

In the terminal, I have given the following command.

```
cd darknet
make
```

I am getting the following error

```
Yolo_mark-master/main.cpp:71:17: error: no member named
  'SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow' in namespace 'cv'
cv::Ptr<cv::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow> sync_PyrLKOpticalFlow;

Yolo_mark-master/main.cpp:59:37: error: no member named
   'SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow' in namespace 'cv'
sync_PyrLKOpticalFlow = cv::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::create();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of yolo? v3 or v2?

Comment: For now, I am setting up yolo_mark for marking bounded boxes of objects in images for training Yolo v3 and v2
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/Yolo_mark
will use yolo v3

Comment: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/Yolo_mark/issues/158 try using opencv 2.4.X or an older version of yolo mark